# IFNULL query gives 2 rows of the same result

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make a yearly report in my project. I am having difficulty in getting this query to return the count in 1 row. The result shows 1 row if there's no transaction with a different year (like 2016 in this case).

When I insert transaction with a different year than 'this' year when executing this code, the result shows 2 rows with same result:

```
select
  ifnull((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM (transaction)WHERE((Month(date)=1)AND (YEAR(date)='2017'))),0) AS `Jan`,
  ifnull((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM (transaction)WHERE((Month(date)=2)AND (YEAR(date)='2017'))),0) AS `Feb`,
  ifnull((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM (transaction)WHERE((Month(date)=3)AND (YEAR(date)='2017'))),0) AS `Mar`,
  ifnull((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM (transaction)WHERE((Month(date)=4)AND (YEAR(date)='2017'))),0) AS `Apr`,
  ifnull((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM (transaction)WHERE((Month(date)=5)AND (YEAR(date)='2017'))),0) AS `May`,
  ifnull((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM (transaction)WHERE((Month(date)=6)AND (YEAR(date)='2017'))),0) AS `Jun`,
  ifnull((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM (transaction)WHERE((Month(date)=7)AND (YEAR(date)='2017'))),0) AS `Jul`,
  ifnull((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM (transaction)WHERE((Month(date)=8)AND (YEAR(date)='2017'))),0) AS `Aug`,
  ifnull((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM (transaction)WHERE((Month(date)=9)AND (YEAR(date)='2017'))),0) AS `Sep`,
  ifnull((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM (transaction)WHERE((Month(date)=10)AND (YEAR(date)='2017'))),0) AS `Oct`,
  ifnull((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM (transaction)WHERE((Month(date)=11)AND (YEAR(date)='2017'))),0) AS `Nov`,
  ifnull((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM (transaction)WHERE((Month(date)=12)AND (YEAR(date)='2017'))),0) AS `Dec`
from transaction GROUP BY YEAR(date)
```

Is there any way to fix this or another queries that can make it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want only the data for 2017 you should filter for this in where

```
select
      ifnull((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM (transaction)WHERE((Month(date)=1)AND (YEAR(date)='2017'))),0) AS `Jan`,
      ifnull((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM (transaction)WHERE((Month(date)=2)AND (YEAR(date)='2017'))),0) AS `Feb`,
      ifnull((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM (transaction)WHERE((Month(date)=3)AND (YEAR(date)='2017'))),0) AS `Mar`,
      ifnull((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM (transaction)WHERE((Month(date)=4)AND (YEAR(date)='2017'))),0) AS `Apr`,
      ifnull((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM (transaction)WHERE((Month(date)=5)AND (YEAR(date)='2017'))),0) AS `May`,
      ifnull((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM (transaction)WHERE((Month(date)=6)AND (YEAR(date)='2017'))),0) AS `Jun`,
      ifnull((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM (transaction)WHERE((Month(date)=7)AND (YEAR(date)='2017'))),0) AS `Jul`,
      ifnull((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM (transaction)WHERE((Month(date)=8)AND (YEAR(date)='2017'))),0) AS `Aug`,
      ifnull((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM (transaction)WHERE((Month(date)=9)AND (YEAR(date)='2017'))),0) AS `Sep`,
      ifnull((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM (transaction)WHERE((Month(date)=10)AND (YEAR(date)='2017'))),0) AS `Oct`,
      ifnull((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM (transaction)WHERE((Month(date)=11)AND (YEAR(date)='2017'))),0) AS `Nov`,
      ifnull((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM (transaction)WHERE((Month(date)=12)AND (YEAR(date)='2017'))),0) AS `Dec`
     from transaction 
     where YEAR(date)='2017'
    GROUP BY YEAR(date)
```

otherwise for each you you have in your data the same select in ifnull (related  to 2017 ) are performed  and return the same values

You could avoid unuseful () and subselect  eg:

```
select
      sum(case when month(date)=1 and YEAR(date) = '2017' then 1 else 0 end ) as 'Jan'
      sum(case when month(date)=2 and YEAR(date) = '2017' then 1 else 0 end ) as 'Feb'
      ......
      sum(case when month(date)=12 and YEAR(date) = '2017' then 1 else 0 end ) as 'Dec'
 from transaction
  where YEAR(date)='2017'
  GROUP BY YEAR(date)
```

Answer (score 1):

I added a condition in the `SUM` function. If this condition (`Month(date)=1) AND (YEAR(date)='2017'`) returns true, then it will return 1 else return 0.

```
select
SUM(Month(date)=1) AND (YEAR(date)='2017') AS `Jan`,
SUM(Month(date)=2) AND (YEAR(date)='2017') AS `Feb`,
SUM(Month(date)=3) AND (YEAR(date)='2017') AS `Mar`,
SUM(Month(date)=4) AND (YEAR(date)='2017') AS `Apr`,
SUM(Month(date)=5) AND (YEAR(date)='2017') AS `May`,
SUM(Month(date)=6) AND (YEAR(date)='2017') AS `Jun`,
SUM(Month(date)=7) AND (YEAR(date)='2017') AS `Jul`,
SUM(Month(date)=8) AND (YEAR(date)='2017') AS `Aug`,
SUM(Month(date)=9) AND (YEAR(date)='2017') AS `Sep`,
SUM(Month(date)=10) AND (YEAR(date)='2017') AS `Oct`,
SUM(Month(date)=11) AND (YEAR(date)='2017') AS `Nov`,
SUM(Month(date)=12) AND (YEAR(date)='2017') AS `Dec`
from transaction
GROUP BY YEAR(date)
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is generic query.

```
SELECT COUNT(id), YEAR(created) as year, MONTH(created) as mon
FROM transaction
WHERE date IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date) Desc
```

It will give result for all the months with years it found and the one which are missing you can handle in your code.